# Segmentation fault when creating object c++

Tags: c++, oop, segmentation-fault

I have a class in c++, which has a constructor in Matrix.h:

```
private:
int col;
int row;
bool isValid;
int **matrix;

public:
Matrix(int inputInt);
```

and in the Matrix.cpp file :

```
Matrix::Matrix(int inputInt)
{
 row=inputInt;
 col=inputInt;
 for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
     matrix[i]=new int [col];
 for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
     for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
          matrix[i][j]=0;
 isValid=true;
}
```

and in the main.cpp I wrote

```
Matrix a(3);
```

and I got a segmentation fault. Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix` is a pointer to pointer, you need to `new` `matrix` itself at first.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int inputInt)
{
 row=inputInt;
 col=inputInt;
 matrix = new int* [row];
 for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
     matrix[i]=new int [col];
 for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
     for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
          matrix[i][j]=0;
 isValid=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program contains undefined behaviour. You never allocate any storage for `matrix`. It's just pointing at garbage.